# How can I register model created by django-simple-history on admin site?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-simple-history

So, I got a model Question that has a history saved in the model HistoricalQuestion by the django-simple-history package, how do I register it to django admin site?

Other model registering is straightforward

```
admin.site.register(models.Event)
```

But I am not sure how to get it for that package models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was actually quite simple actually. All I had to do was"

```
admin.site.register(models.Question.history.model)
```

Where Question is my model name.